# Decimal value delimiter issue

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, .net-2.0

Not sure how to describe the issue in the title.

I'm saving a price (decimal only, not currency format) to a SQL db.
On Windows 8 computers, if there is a decimal value, the value will move to the left, and become a .00 decimal.

For example:

120.34 will become 12034.00 in the database.

120.00 will be 120.00 in the database.

On windows 7 however we don't face this issue.

```
decimal RetailPrice = Convert.ToDecimal(strPriceValue , CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@retail_price", System.Data.SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = RetailPrice;
```

The sql column type is decimal(16, 2).

I would like to save the decimal value as is, and not needing to change any windows regional culture settings. The source value will always have 2 decimal spaces and a . decimal delimiter, which is how I want it be saved in the database.

I'm so confused why this happens, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Update:

Simple cast and removing the string conversion that fixed this issue:

```
decimal RetailPrice = (decimal)(ds.Tables[1].Rows[m]["Retail_Price"] as double? ?? 0D);
```

Comment: You have your currency settings on two different ways (ed. 0,00 and 0.00), your SQL sees the 0.00 as 000.00 so its logic what it does. A clean build in function does not exist as far as I know, however with a replace and substring you would be able to make this work.

Comment: What is the value of `strPriceValue` when you try? That is important here. Is that what you said `120.34`.?

Comment: The value for example, would be 221872.81 or 175351 format. This value comes from another sql server db, which datatype is a float.
So the source value is a float, the destination value is decimal.
I cannot change the source database float type.

Comment: Did you checked what was the value of `RetailPrice` after converted? Is it `120.34` or `12034`?

Comment: The value is 120.34 on my machine, which is Win7.
I just don't understand why this happens on Win8 machines. I will try and get the value returned from that machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say your source data type is `float` (in the source SQL database).
Your destination data type should be `decimal`. 
So you need a conversion **from float to decimal**.

In your code you have a string value `strPriveValue`

It is the conversion from float to string which causes your trouble, you can avoid this conversion completely.

Comment: Can;t believe it was something so stupid. This is very old code I had to work on. Even though everything worked fine sub Win8 machines, It works on Win8 now. Updated OP with my source code update. Thanks